# Use NSDictionary values between two class

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary, nsobject

I'm trying to get the values ​​within an `NSDictionary` between two classes ..

I use this method in the `Database.m` **(NSObject class)**

```
+(void)fetchAllUserWithReference:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

    FIRDatabaseReference *userReference = [[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:RTDUSER];
    [userReference observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        __block NSDictionary *dict = dictionary;
        dict = snapshot.value;

    } withCancelBlock:nil];
}
```

and I want to get the NSDictionary data in the `Dashboard.m` **(UIView Controller)** class like this ..

```
-(void)retrieveUsers {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    [Database fetchAllUserWithReference:dict];    
    NSLog(@"DICT %@",dict);
}
```

Why is my `NSDictionary` of class `Dashboard.m` always **NULL** ?? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try using +(void)fetchAllUserWithReference:(NSDictionary**)dictionary

Comment: @JayachandraA i dont understand... I try with 2 **??? ( NSDictionary ** ) ?? this you mean???

Comment: I mean use double pointer concept

Comment: @JayachandraA 'NSDictionary *__autoreleasing *' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: @kAiN `observeEventType` is async block, you can receive the value in completion handler.

Comment: @Rocky there are no methods to read data out of the block?

Comment: All of the classes are != nil right? Did you made it as a singleton? or static? Maybe your are creating 2 different instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use completion handler to get values back after executing block.

```
-(void)fetchAllUserWithReference:(NSDictionary *)param
       withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))block{

       FIRDatabaseReference *userReference = [[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:RTDUSER];
      [userReference observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
       NSDictionary *dict = snapshot.value;
       block(dict);
    } withCancelBlock:
   block(nil);];
}

-(void)retrieveUsers {
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary init];
    [self fetchAllUserWithReference:dict withCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *response) {
        NSLog(@"%@",response);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks Rocky